# How to count column in inner join query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi how can I create a query for this in inner join to count also on how many 
id in the stdtbl_detail ?

for example
in stdtbl the id is "372", so I want to count how many 372 in stdtbl_detail

```
SELECT h.*, d.* from
  stdtbl h inner join stdtbl_detail d
  on h.id = d.std_dtl_id

  where
  h.loginid = '1' AND  h.stdid='013777'
```

so the output would be like this

```
id               stdid              loginid          std_dtl_id              countexist   


372              013777                1                  372                    4       

372              013777                1                  372                    4

372              013777                1                 372                     4

372              013777                 1                 372                    4

373              013777                1                  373                    4  

373              013777                 1                  373                    4

373              013777                 1                   373                   4

373              013777                1                     373                   4
```

Thank you in advance

here is the [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6eccf/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select h.*
     , d.*
     , count(*)
from stdtbl h
inner join stdtbl_detail d on h.id = d.std_dtl_id
where h.loginid = '1'
  and  h.stdid ='013777'
group by id
```

That will give you an answer. Do you need each `id` to show up every time, or just once per `id`?

[**Updated SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6eccf/2)

**EDIT**

This one will give you exactly what you asked for, just in case you also need that

```
select h.*
     , d.*
from stdtbl h  
inner join (
    select std_dtl_id
         , count(*) total
    from stdtbl_detail
    group by std_dtl_id
) d on h.id = d.std_dtl_id
inner join stdtbl_detail dt on h.id = dt.std_dtl_id
where h.loginid = '1'
  and  h.stdid = '013777'
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6eccf/6)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT h.*, d.* , count(*) 
FROM stdtbl h 
INNER JOIN stdtbl_detail d ON h.id = d.std_dtl_id
WHERE h.loginid = '1' AND  h.stdid='013777'
GROUP BY h.id
```